# Prevent Activity from closing when original Activity is finished

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm writing an application that fetches information from the web before it can function correctly. I therefore wrote an InitialActivity that shows a loading screen at startup.
A button on this initial screen allows to go to an InfoActivity while you're waiting. If the loading is finished while the InfoActivity is running, this InfoActivity stops and the MainActivity that succeeds the InitialActivity starts.

The InitialActivity contains the method that starts the InfoActivity. Loading from the webpage is performed using an inner-class defined AsyncTask. If loading is successful, the onPostExecute() method starts the mainactivity.

```
public class InitialActivity extends Activity{  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_initial);

        new RequestTask().execute(getString(R.string.website));
    }

    public void startInfoActivity(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... uri){
        //DO THE INFORMATION FETCHIN
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean passed) {
        super.onPostExecute(passed);

        if(passed){
            //SAVE THE FETCHED INFORMATION


            //close this activity and lauch main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(InitialActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to block the automatic shutdown of the InfoActivity when the loading in the AsyncTask is finished? When the user then selects to leave the InfoActivity, the MainActivity should show up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't understand the question here... Can you be more precise (with a simple diagram) ? (http://yuml.me/ can help for diagrams)

Comment: Apply a check before starting `MainActivity` via `Intent`.

Comment: @ChristopheCVB http://yuml.me/394a7c83 Something like this?

Comment: as per this code, the infoactivity does nt seem to have been finished. so on back press m sure ul reach the info activity

Comment: So, you want to show `InfoActivity` only if there is an user interaction and cancel the `AsyncTask` to prevent the `onPostExecute()` call, is that right ?

Comment: Typical user case:
start app
Initial activity launches, loading files from the web.
While waiting, user can check out information about the app in an InfoActivity.
When, in the background, the loading (defined in an asynctask) is finished, the InfoActivity is aborted and the app initiates the MainActivity. 
It should be possible to stay in the InfoActivity, and only return to the MainActivity when the user says so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

onPostExecute method change with this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```